# How can I change the appearance of ListPreference **Button**

Tags: android, user-interface, listpreference

There are a lot of questions around how to customize a `ListPreference` with images on each row and so on.
What i m interested is, however, the button that opens up the list dialog.

For example, for the sync frequency :

[image]

Is there a way to replace the generic listpref button with an image button ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `android:icon` attribute to add an image to your ListPreference entry.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3aicon)